# Regular expression for positive and a negative decimal value in java

Tags: java, regex

Regular expression for negative and positive decimal value so that can be 
matched with string using pattern and matcher for the correct implementation 
can any one will provide me with that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))
```

Comment: Replace the second + with a * to match things like ".4" as well (credited to the notes in the incorrect answer below).

Comment: For anyone using this to do validation on number-only text boxes, if your regex engine supports it, you can wrap the expression with start and end anchors, like so `^(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))$`.

Comment: @kevin628 remember that some regex engines need to have a flag turned on to use those start and end anchors. I know for instance that Java regular expressions need (?m) at the start to use the `^` and `$` symbols.

Answer (score 8):

Try This!  I've also used this way

```
"^-?[0-9]{1,12}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$"
```

Rules:

```
ex: ^-?[0-9]{1,12}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
^           # Start of string
[0-9]{1,12} # Match 1-12 digits (i. e. 0-999999999999)
(?:         # Try to match...
\.          # a decimal point
[0-9]{1,4}  # followed by one to three digits (i. e. 0-9999)
)?          # ...optionally
$            # End of string
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[+-]?\d+\.\d+
```

Comment: Note that this will fail to recognize patterns like ".4" (no leading zero) or "10" (no decimal).  But given the vagueness of the "question," I have no idea if that's a problem or not.

Comment: yeah; since OP said "decimal", I think decimal point is mandatory, but I'm also unsure about that optional integer

Comment: Well, if we go with the mandatory decimal point, could always do it as "[+-]?\d*\.\d+".  Handles the optional leading 0, at least.

Comment: 'Decimal' does not mean non-integer. What if OP had said 'binary' or 'octal'? All those qualifiers just limit the range of digits.  All such numbers may or may not have a fraction.

Comment: @BlairHippo has the closest to functioning answer I was able to find.  Got me close enough to arrive at @"^([+-]?\d*\.\d+)$"

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (BOOL)isStringADecimalNumber:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *regex = @"([+]|-)?(([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)|([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+))";

    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    BOOL stringIsADecimalNumber = [test evaluateWithObject:string];

    return stringIsADecimalNumber;
}
```

Highlighted below, are the numbers that return **`TRUE`** for this regex:
[image]
[image]