# Regular Expression - Decimal

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to extract positive integers, negative integers, positive decimal number and negative decimal number using **Regex**?

I have been using `-\d+` regular expression to get both positive and negative numbers.

Valid Numbers:

```
-1
-1.0 
1
1.0
```

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072222/regular-expression-for-positive-and-a-negative-decimal-value-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2 - maybe it will help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex

```
[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

would accept numbers like

```
1123
1.00
+123213
-123.234324
```

if you also like to match numbers like .23 you have can use

```
[+-]?(?:(?:\d+)|(?:\d*\.\d+))
```

Comment: how would i check for JUST "special characters" like "-" or "+"?

Comment: You only want to match - or +? just use [+-]

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
^[+-]?(\d+(\.?\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

Matches all your examples, and numbers like:

- `+1.0`
- `.56`
- `+.56`
- `-.56`

Comment: Does your expression match `1.`?  Should it?

Comment: @EricLippert Whoops, sorry. Fixed.